# Trouble safeguarding form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I have an HTML table with rows representing database records.  The last column's cell has a form with a submit button for deleting the database record.  The forms have unique IDs, but the fields within them just have names, and those names are the same for each form.

I have a simple user confirmation, but I want to make sure the form doesn't just submit due to Javascript not running (an error or something).  So I thought I would leave the value of one of the hidden fields blank and fill it in at the time of the submit (a field that is required by the processing script but is the same value no matter which record is chosen, so it's easy to assign).  Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[id^='deltrans']").submit(function(e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?")) {
      $(this).find("[name='uri']").val("my value...");
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

But using $(this).find() doesn't seem to work - Firebug says $(this).find("[name='uri']").val() is undefined.  Can you either see my error or have a better, simpler suggestion for how to prevent accidental form submissions if there is a JS issue?

EDIT: Per the requests in the comments, here is the relevent HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="deltrans<? echo $row->TransID; ?>" action="processor.php">
  <td class="button-in-table">
    <input type="hidden" name="tid" value="<? echo $row->TransID; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="deltrans" value="Del">
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: Does `.filter()` work any better than `.find()`?

Comment: Please show HTML. You must not have a DOM element within your form that has a name of `uri`. `$(this)` should be giving you the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Edited to add HTML - sorry I didn't do that the first time.

Comment: Any other thoughts on this?  Currently I left my code in a state where the delete will happen if JS is not running or gets an error, but surely there is a standard way that people code forms so that that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the `uri` input is inside the form couldn't you use:

`$(this).children('[name^=uri]').val("my value...");`

In its entirety:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form[id^='deltrans']").submit(function(e) {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?")) {
      $(this).children('[name^=uri]').val("my value...");
   } else {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: children() was what I tried first, but then I realized that it was actually a grandchild, so I changed to find().